# Visual Basic - Copying the only Recently Modified Files to another Folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010

the following code I have hear will extract all the files inside of a certain folder, and then copy all of them and place them into another folder.  My question today is how do I modify this code so that only files extracted from the original folder have been recently modified. Even if you could show me how to extract only the files that have been modified from today would be great. Thanks to all of you who help!

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmExtractionator

Dim txtFiles1 As Control

Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

    Dim sourceDirectory As String = "E:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone"
    Dim archiveDirectory As String = "E:\FilesExtracted"

    Try
        'DeleteUnmodifiedFiles(sourceDirectory, -14)

        Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory)

        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(archiveDirectory)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveDirectory)
        End If



        For Each currentFileLoc As String In txtFiles
            Dim fileName = currentFileLoc.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)
            File.Move(currentFileLoc, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))
        Next
    Catch eT As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Directory.GetLastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getlastwritetime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method to determine when the file was last written to.

From Link:

> Returns the date and time the specified file or directory was last written to.

```
Dim checkDate As Date = Date.Parse("01/1/2013")

For Each currentFileLoc As String In txtFiles
    Dim fileName = currentFileLoc.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)
    If Directory.GetLastWriteTime(Path.Combine(sourceDirectory, fileName)) > checkDate Then
        File.Move(currentFileLoc, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))
    End If
Next
```